# Trying to print only if the operation is executed

Tags: python, pushbullet

i am pretty bad with using python but im trying to learn. So i have a script that extracts .zip and .rar files for me and that works flawlessly, now the only thing i want to implement is that if the script extracts a .zip or a .rar i want it to use Pushbullet to send a notification to my phone. This is being achieved with [pushbullet.py](https://github.com/randomchars/pushbullet.py)

Anyway here is the script as of now:

```
import os
from subprocess import check_call
from os.path import join
from pushbullet import Pushbullet
from pyunpack import Archive

pb = Pushbullet("APIkey")
path = "/mnt/synology/Torrents/completed"
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    if not any(f.endswith(".mkv") for f in files):
        for file in files:
            pth = join(root, file)
            found_r = False
            try:
                 if file.endswith(".zip"):
                    push = pb.push_note("NUC", "Extracting")
                    Archive(pth).extractall(root)
                    found_zip = True
                 elif not found_r and file.endswith((".rar")):
                     push = pb.push_note("NUC", "Extracting")
                     Archive(pth).extractall(root)
                     found_r = True
                     break

            except:
                pass
```

So right now it's pushing to my phone on every match it finds which is many matches and not what i want. I want it to push on just a successfull Extraction.

Does anyone know of a solution ?

Comment: move the call to the push function to a different place? (e.g.: after the loop)

Comment: I cant get it to work, if i put it at the bottom like this:

    `push = pb.push_note("Extracted", "Test" )`
It still wouldnt work

Comment: Maybe check if the new files/folders have been created, and if they have then send the push?

Comment: What does "it wouldn't work" mean? Do you get an error, does it not send the notification, ...? You need to be specific if something is not working as you intended, otherwise we cannot help you